# NativeScript Http POST body parameters are not specified

Tags: post, angular, nativescript

I'm trying to learn and test out NativeScript + Angular2 and I am trying to perform a simple post request that I've tested in Postman and it should work as expected yet I am getting a 400 error saying:

> {"error":{"code":400,"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"client_id not specified","message":"client_id not specified","details":[]}}

Note the "client_id not specified"...

I'm sure that from reading documentation that i am specifying the client_id

I've tried a bunch of different header configs and I've read the NativeScript documentation and Angular 2 documentation but I'm not quite sure what the problem is here.

Here is my code below

```
getToken() {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let body = JSON.stringify({
        client_id: Config.clientid,
        client_secret: Config.clientsecret,
        grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    })

    console.log("Body: " +  body);
    // Body: {"client_id":"12345","client_secret":"98765","grant_type":"client_credentials"}

    return this.http.post(
        Config.tokenUrl,
        body,
        { headers: headers }
    )
    .map(response => {
        let data = response.json()
        console.log("Result: " + data.toString());
        // Result: {"error":{"code":400,"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"client_id not specified","message":"client_id not specified","details":[]}}
        Config.token = data.Result.token;
        console.log("Token: " + Config.token);
        return data;
    })
    .catch(this.handleErrors);
}
```

I'm also having problems using Fiddler to capture the actual communication, which is a something else I'm working on fixing. But in the mean time, any ideas?

---

**Update**

I found that if i do this:

```
    let body =  'client_id=' + Config.clientid + '&client_secret=' + Config.clientsecret + '&grant_type=client_credentials';
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

it works.

Comment: did you try let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");   and add  { headers: headers } in  your http post like here https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/5005de45325811ebe60a3e6f997b2d999bdee0ab/app/shared/login.service.ts

Comment: Yeah and if i do this:

let body =  'client_id=' + Config.clientid + '&client_secret=' + Config.clientsecret + '&grant_type=client_credentials';
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

it works...